# import huge excel sheets to Datatable

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a Excel Sheet with two tabs.

One is approx 700 k and other is around 25k. The issue is when i am loading the files my memory gets eaten up and it crashes! How to handle huge files as some might even be more than a million rows.

Here is my current code i am using:

```
  OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
                cnn.Open();

                string qry = "SELECT * FROM [Detail$]";
                OleDbDataAdapter odp = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry, cnn);
                odp.Fill(detailTable);
                DataSet tmp = new DataSet();
                if (detailTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Total " + detailTable.Rows.Count + " Detail rows Loaded");
                    // MessageBox.Show("Input Sheet UPLOADED !");

                }
                qry = "SELECT * FROM [Gallery$]";
                OleDbDataAdapter odp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry, cnn);
                odp1.Fill(galleryTable);
                if (galleryTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Total " + galleryTable.Rows.Count + " Gallery Numbers Loaded");
                    //  MessageBox.Show("Input Sheet UPLOADED !");

                }
```

Comment: Not sure yet what you are looking for - if all data can't fit into memory you have only two options - not load all data or use more memory/address space (most likely need x64 for that). You need more information on your restrictions/goals in question to get good answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's very important to load the tabs completely especially the bigger one as it is searched within ....

Comment: Sorry if you find this a silly question, but do you need all the columns?

Comment: @AndyG actually its a smart question , i believe i do not :|. I just need 5-6 out of 56 nt sure why it did not came to my mind.

Comment: I am choosing the answer based on the most helpful one. Which can be utilized in other conditions where i have to select all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, what I can suggest you is to use the `DbDataAdapter.Fill(Int32, Int32, DataTable[])` overload method of the `DbDataAdapter` class to work in a "chunk" mode:

```
public int Fill(
    int startRecord,
    int maxRecords,
    params DataTable[] dataTables
)
```

Using this method and my code example, you can do your job with chunks of rows at a time instead of working with the full excel data in-memory. After each fill, dispose your temp data-table object and you'll be able to avoid of memory leaks this way.

Here is how you can do it:

```
        const string fileName = "myData.xlsx";
        const string excelConnString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        using (var cnn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
        {
            cnn.Open();

            const string countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Detail$]";
            using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(countQuery, cnn))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader == null) return;

                    reader.Read();
                    var rowsCount = ((int)reader[0]);

                    const string query = "SELECT * FROM [Detail$]";
                    using (var odp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnn))
                    {
                        var detailTable = new DataTable();
                        var recordToStartFetchFrom = 0; //zero-based record number to start with.
                        const int chunkSize = 100;
                        while (recordToStartFetchFrom <= rowsCount)
                        {
                            var diff = rowsCount - recordToStartFetchFrom;
                            int internalChunkSize = diff < 100 ? diff : chunkSize;
                            odp.Fill(recordToStartFetchFrom, internalChunkSize, detailTable);

                            foreach (DataRow row in detailTable.Rows)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{1} {0}", row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1]);
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("--------- {0}-{1} Rows Processed ---------", recordToStartFetchFrom, recordToStartFetchFrom + internalChunkSize);

                            recordToStartFetchFrom += chunkSize;

                            detailTable.Dispose();
                            detailTable = null;
                            detailTable = new DataTable();
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nope no Database interaction is done .... i just need to load the rows as simply as possible....

Comment: Yes excel sheets to DataTable but i like suggestion , but how can we determine the end of the record? just keep going on until i get a null table?

Comment: We need to predefined a maxRows to fetch, let's say 100, and according to the total rows in the excel sheets we will use a modulo operator to determine each 100. if we have 1000, than each 100 records fill the table - i.e 10 times...

Comment: @ int rowsCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()); is throwing exception (input string not in correct format)

Comment: @confusedMind fix the exception

Comment: what did you add to the code above can you please paste here?

Comment: @confusedMind Please take my entire code again because I changed and add few code lines.

Comment: Just an observation, but 100 seems a small number. I would explore 500 then 1000 (possibly more).

Comment: i am doing 10000 :| and its wokring but my Ram is showing 3.46 out of 4 Gb used .. Now 3.49,, looks like with each new chunk it increases ?

Comment: @confusedMind You're right, I fixed it, I add `detailTable.Dispose()`

Comment: Perfect , if i combine @AndyG and yours answer together i get a really good one fast and no memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to load large amount of data in memory (i.e. 1M rows * 1Kb per row ~ 1GB) your only reasonably option is to use build 64bit (x64) application as address space restriction on x86 application (2GB on normal x86 system, up to 4GB on x64 system) will not allow to allocate enough memory.

Notes:

- going x64 may not be possible in some cases (i.e. lack of x64 native libraries used via some sort of PInvoke)
- you may be able to fit more rows in memory in x86 process if using carefully designed custom classes for rows. I.e. some values may be present in your DB as strings and can be represented as enum of 1-4 byte long instead of strings in memory.
- consider moving search to DB/Excel instead of using custom in-memory search.
- if sticking with x86 make sure not to load more than 1 copy of data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Only select the 5 or 6 columns that you need.